# Serilog 3.4 and ASPNET core 2.1 stops logging after 3 lines when initialized through configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I am integrating Serilog into an existing aspnet core 2.1 WebHost app. My single dependency is Serilog.AspNetCore Version 3.4.0.

When I initialize the logger using configuration in WebHost builder, I get 3 lines in the log file and no other logging. When I initialize the logger completely in code in main, logging works as expected.

Serilog initialization through configuration (only 3 lines output):

appsettings.json:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Level}] {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "path": "/var/log/somedir/somefile.log"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The builder code:

```
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => 
            loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
```

Serilog initialization in main (logging works as expected):

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File("/var/log/somedir/somefile.log", outputTemplate:"[{Level}] {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
        .CreateLogger();
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Some service is starting");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
```

Code in the builder:

```
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
```

Note that I'm pretty sure configuration is being read or the output would not be in the file specified in configuration.

Could the Microsoft logging stuff be smashing the Serilog stuff?

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The [Serilog Documentation describes how to enable Self-Log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) for troubleshooting. Have you tried that?

Comment: @mason Thank you for pointing me to the selflog facility. I enabled SelfLog like so:  Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***"+msg));
 in main() and I don't see output from that either running in VSCode or as a service.

Comment: I am curious, did you find out why?
I am facing a similar weird situation while writing Azure IoT Edge Modules in C#. One module logs just fine, but in another module ..after the init logs nothing appears!